# jQuery - variable interval

Tags: jquery, intervals

Here's my current code:

```
$(document).ready( function() {

// set variables
var delay = 3000;

setInterval( function() {

    // perform AJAX call
    var req = $.ajax({
        url: "view/jquery/jq.refresh.php",
        dataType: "json"
    });

    // process data from json
    req.done( function(data) {
        $("#now_playing").html(data.song);
        $("#queue_list").html(data.queue);

        delay = data.time;
    });        

}, delay);
});
```

...and it's not working as planned.

The idea was to retrieve a variable delay (length of a song) from a database with AJAX. And put that delay (length of the song) into `setInterval`, this way the script would loop at variable intervals depending on the length of the song that is playing, hopefully reducing server/database load.

I'm sure that the correct value for the delay is retrieved from the database as adding `console.log(date.time);` shows me the length of the song.

One theory I have why my code won't work is that `setInterval` reads its ms value before actually processing the code within, so it's always set to `3000`.
Another theory is that `delay = data.time` doesn't change `delay` value because it's a global variable set at the start of the script.

So what options do I have to achieve a variable interval without crashing/freezing the browser?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since interval is set when initial call to `setInterval` made. modifying the value of `delay` will have no effect.

You should use `setTimeout` in this scenario.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    // set variables
    var delay = 3000;

    //Define a function
    function getData() {

        // perform AJAX call
        var req = $.ajax({
            url: "view/jquery/jq.refresh.php",
            dataType: "json"
        });

        // process data from json
        req.done(function(data) {
            $("#now_playing").html(data.song);
            $("#queue_list").html(data.queue);

            delay = data.time;
            //Schedule the subsequent execution 
            setTimeout(getData, data.time);
        });
    }

    //Schedule to execute after 3 seconds on page load
    setTimeout(getData, delay);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

> setInterval reads its ms value before actually processing the code within, so it's always set to 3000

Yes. You only call `setInterval` once, and it's while the `delay` is set to 3000. Changing the value of `delay` after that point will have no affect on the already scheduled interval.

If you want a variable interval, you cannot use `setInterval`. Use `setTimeout`, and have each callback enqueue its subsequent callback.

```
function pollNext() {
    // perform AJAX call
    var req = $.ajax({
        url: "view/jquery/jq.refresh.php",
        dataType: "json"
    });

    // process data from json
    req.done( function(data) {
        $("#now_playing").html(data.song);
        $("#queue_list").html(data.queue);

       setTimeout(pollNext, data.time);
    });     

}

pollNext(); // Prime the initial invocation
```

Answer (score 0):

The `delay` of a call to `setInterval()` is only read once - when the interval is declared. Your attempt at changing the `delay` variable after instantiation will have no effect.

The alternative method is to chain `setTimeout()` calls, as you can then change the delay of the next timeout. Try this:

```
function createTimeout(delay) {
    setTimeout(function() {   
        $.ajax({
            url: "view/jquery/jq.refresh.php",
            dataType: "json"
        }).done(function(data) {
            $("#now_playing").html(data.song);
            $("#queue_list").html(data.queue);
            createTimeout(data.time);
        });            
    }, delay);
}

createTimeout(3000);
```